# Stop blender UI overflowing?

Tags: interface

[image]

In the above image, I am using a very popular addon called Boxcutter. Boxcutter has a very extensive selection of options that you can see in the bottom row right above my windows taskbar - However, because there are so many, they are overflowing.

I want to be able to see all the commands available to me and not have them overflow and become unhidden.

How do i change the overflow mechanism so that the commands either become smaller in text size or wrap to a second row or have some ability to scroll left and right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> have some ability to scroll left and right

Blender in any situation except when a tool like `Boxcutter` is being used, does  have scroll functionality. I guess the inability to scroll when external plugin tools are enabled could be considered a bug. Might be useful to flag this as a potential issue to the development team

[image].

Answer (score 4):

You can try changing the interface resolution scale to fit more text on the info bar or check the [boxcutter documentation](https://boxcutter-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the hotkeys.

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, but im still going to leave the question open as a smaller UI really isn't *that* pleasant to use